# mvc gridview with code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how to get a gridview in model view control,how to edit,delete the gridview with source code

Comment: I know of at least two upvotes for this question?  Why?

Answer (score 3):

Telerik has a great grid that's free (open source) for MVC.  You can view it here, and the download is on their web site.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to ASP.NET controls in ASP.NET MVC, well not with the postback and viewstate stuff atleast.

However, you can create a nice GridView with ajax edit/delete capabilities by using something like jqGrid and a little code. Here are a couple of blog posts to get you started :

- [Full Walkthrough of MvcContrib Grid with jQuery Data table](http://blogs.msdn.com/paulwhit/archive/2009/03/28/walkthrough-full-example-of-using-mvccontrib-grid-with-jquery-datatable.aspx)
- [Using jQuery Grid With ASP.NET MVC](http://74.125.153.132/search?q=cache:-TPac2uLLtoJ:haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx+jqgrid+site:haacked.com+asp.net+mvc&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in&client=firefox-a)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

[Paginated List](http://www.networkozone.com/snippets/c-sharp/1/paginated-list)
Divides IQueryable source of any type on pages and returns items for current page. Useful for creating custom gridviews and pagers in C#, ASP.NET WebForms or MVC. Althought this code is used for pagnition, there is example on how to create Gridview with paging. Shouldn't be too hard to create CRUD actions from it.