# Create GridView in asp.net MVC3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to create grid in asp.net MVc3.0. The gridview that is used in asp.net similar to that if yes then please let me know how to create a simple grid in asp.net mvc3.0 I m using sql server Database to fetch data, that has to be filled in grid. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are different possibilities:

Server side grids:

- The built-in [WebGrid helper](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrebaltieri/archive/2010/11/01/asp-net-mvc-3-working-with-webgrid.aspx)
- [MvcContrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid)
- [Telerik Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx)

Client-Side grids:

- [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)
- [YUI DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/)

and many others...

Comment: jqGrid sucks...  Well let me not be negative.  Its not easy to work with by any means, but it does the job.

Comment: @darin what is the difference between client side grid and server side grid

Comment: The first is generated on the client using javascript and the second is generated on the server.

Comment: First link to WebGrid helper is broken. 
Please don't just include links without actual data or examples!

Answer (score 13):

You can use WebGrid in MVC3.  This is new in MVC3.
Use this code in your View.

```
@model IList<YourViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Amend Absence";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 200, 
    canPage: false, canSort: true, defaultSort: "Absentee");
 }
<p>
    <h2>Absentee List</h2>
        <div id="grid">
            @grid.GetHtml(
                tableStyle: "grid",
                headerStyle: "head",
                alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", 
                new { id =   item.Id     })), 
                grid.Column("Absentee", "Absentee",canSort:true),
                grid.Column("AbsStart", "AbsStartDate")
            ))
      </div>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 3):

See the excellent [Get the Most Out of WebGrid in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/hh288075.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create it using TABLE / TR / TD tags.

Here is few links which may help you

1. [mvc gridview with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997861/mvc-gridview-with-code)
2. http://www.schnieds.com/2010/01/gridview-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: 2nd link is dead