# how make dynamic gridview in asp.net mvc3 aspx

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have make a dynamic gridview in asp.net mvc3 view engine is aspx. i have to bind datasource  gridview. how bind datasource to grid view. and i had to add templete in gridview.

Answer (score 1):

You could have found this answer yourself if you would do some research but here are some links that could help you:

http://weblogs.asp.net/andrebaltieri/archive/2010/11/01/asp-net-mvc-3-working-with-webgrid.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/10/08/using-the-webgrid-helper-in-asp-net-mvc-3-beta.aspx

http://www.unboxedsolutions.com/sean/archive/2011/01/23/15964.aspx

could be something like this:

```
@{
var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: ThisController.PageSize, canSort: true,    ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
grid.Bind(Model.Employees, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
@grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id="grid" },
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { EmployeeID = item.EmployeeID, ContactID = item.ContactID })),
        grid.Column("FullName"),
        grid.Column("Title")
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MVC .NET or WebForms?

Which grid view are you talking about?

Have you seen these links:

[Create GridView in asp.net MVC3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138618/create-gridview-in-asp-net-mvc3-0)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1687421.aspx/1?Gridview+in+MVC+3